# How to set custom template for kendo-ui multiselect with angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-formly

I was trying to create custom template for multiselect with kedno-ui multiselect and angular-formly. I can get only normal select dropdown field without multisecetion... 
Here is my example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vezuqaz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with Configuring app run.

```
 `app.run(function (formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'multiSelect',
        extends: 'select',
        template: '<select kendo-multi-select k-options="" ng-model="model[options.key]" class="form-control" multiple></select>'
    });
});`
```

And setting filed like this.

```
`vm.fields = [       
  {
    key: 'multiSelect',
    type: 'multiSelect',
    templateOptions: {
      type: 'multiSelect',
      label: 'Fruits',          
      options: data
    }
  },`
```

You can see example [here](http://jsbin.com/vezuqaz/edit?js,output)